# why dojo 2 doesn't take an already created framework as base?

Tags: javascript, dojo

why `dojo2` doesn't take an already created framework as base. For example they could use `angular2` as base and then only create the widgets.

why they want to create everything from scratch? Is there any advantage on doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Angular and Dojo are two different things.

Dojo is a JavaScript toolkit. Provides everything you need to build a Web app. From widgets, utilities, pub/sub, aol programming even a build tool and much more.

AngularJS is a specialized structural framework for dynamic web apps.

The advantage of dojo is that cover majority of aspects needed for a complex Web app with a standard API.

If you would use instead several combination of frameworks, would be more difficult to achieve such uniformity.

Interestingly Dojo2 now use an external library for virtual dom called [maquettejs](http://maquettejs.org/) for its widget system, but I believe it is a special case otherwise dojo itself is quite comprehensive toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, apart from dojo's modularity and different goal :

dojo appeared in 2005 ([history](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/quickstart/introduction/history.html))

and angular appeared in 2009

Note that [dojo2](http://dojo.io) is beta.

They could use angular (but why a new isolated product) or polymer (but not serverside) or react (but not typescripted) but why should they change the philosophy behind the widget system at all. They recently decided to support TSX which is a react like syntax.